# .sln are all external references in there

Tags: visual-studio, reference

I have develop some Web Application with Visual Studio. Now, I have a solution file(.sln) for my application. It is possible to open this file on another PC and bring them to work. Despite there are many references from Third-Party-Tools.

So in short, are all references in a solution file included? Which mean on a external PC I don't need to include some external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in short, are all references in a solution file included?

It depends on how you reference the third-party files. Ideally, all third-party files should be part of the solution so anyone who opens it can build it.

To achieve that, either use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) or add a Depedencies folder for your third-party files and when you add a reference to the Solution ensure you use the Depedencies folder.

In short, nothing is worse than opening a solution and finding it won't complile.